# Add "+" before every line that gets shown by grep

Tags: grep, command

```
grep -Fxvf file1.txt file2.txt
```

this shows me The difference between the two Files, which is:

```
Name A
Name B
Name C
```

but I want that it shows me a "+" before every line. Like this: (I dont want to edit the files, just the output)

```
+Name A
+Name B
+Name C
```

How can I add a "+" before every line?

Comment: Welcome, have you tried something so far? `grep` doesn't add extra content to the output, just retrieves what is in the input. Does the input contain `+` signs? If so could you **[edit]** the question adding relevant sample data?

Comment: If you're looking for the differences between two files (which, btw, your grep command doesn't actually give you - it just gives you the lines that are in file2.txt that aren't in file1.txt, which is not the same thing), you probably want to read the man pages for `comm` and `diff` (see especially diff's `-u` option - e.g. try `diff -u File1 File2 | grep '^+[^+]'`)

Answer (score 4):

I wonder if this is what you're looking for:

```
grep -Fxvf file1.txt file2.txt | sed 's/^/+/'
```

I am redirecting the pipe, i.e. the `grep` output, to another program, i.e. `sed`, which is used to `s`ubstitute the beginning of each line, i.e. `^`, with the `+` symbol you're looking for.

if you want to redirect the final output into a file, i.e. export the output, then, this is what you may want to do:

```
grep -Fxvf file1.txt file2.txt | sed 's/^/+/' > export.txt
```

Also, if you need to find the differences between two files, you may want to look for a specifically designed utility, which is `diff`. Find some info [here](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html).